# Memory error, access violation

Tags: c

I'm learning C on my own and as a exercise i have written a program but it does not work. The program is splitted into 3 parts. A header file, a main file for executing the program a file to define the functions. I'm not using all the functions yet but that shouldn't be the problem.

Here is my header file, nothing special in it.

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

struct Employee
{
    char first[21];
    char last[21];
    char title[21];
    int salary;
};

    struct Employee* createEmployee(char*, char*, char*, int); // Creates a struct Employee object on the heap.
    char* getfirstname (struct Employee*); 
    char* getlastname (struct Employee*);
    char* gettitle (struct Employee*);
    int getsalary (struct Employee*);

    void setfirstname (struct Employee*, char*); 
    void setlastname (struct Employee*, char*);
    void settitle (struct Employee*, char*);
    void setsalary (struct Employee*, int);

    void printEmployee(struct Employee*);

#endif
```

In this file i define the functions and how they work:

```
#include "7.1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Employee* createEmployee(char* first, char* last, char* title, int salary) // Creates a struct Employee object on the heap.
{
    struct Employee* p =  (struct Employee*) malloc(sizeof(struct Employee)); 

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(p->first, first);
        strcpy(p->last, last);
        strcpy(p->title, title);
        p->salary = salary;
    }
    return p;

}

char* getfirstname (struct Employee* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        return p ? p->first : "";
    }

char* getlastname (struct Employee* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        return p ? p->last : "";

    }

char* gettitle (struct Employee* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        return p ? p->title : "";

    }

int getsalary (struct Employee* p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        return p ? p->salary : 0;

    }

void setfirstname (struct Employee* p, char* first)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p->first, first);
    }


void setlastname (struct Employee* p, char* last)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p->last, last);
    }

void settitle (struct Employee* p, char* title)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p->title, title);
    }

void setsalary (struct Employee* p, char* salary)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        p->salary = salary;
    }



void printEmployee(struct Employee* p)

    {
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s, %s, %s, %d",
                    p->first,
                    p->last,
                    p->salary,
                    p->salary
            );
        }

    }
```

And the last file is used to executed the program/functions:

```
#include "7.1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()

{
    char decision;
    struct Employee emp;
    struct Employee* emps[3];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i ++)
   {
       printf("Please type in the emplooyes data.\nFirstname:");
           scanf("%s", emp.first);

       printf("Lastname:");
           scanf("%s", emp.last);

       printf("Title:");
           scanf("%s", emp.title);

       printf("Salary:");
           scanf("%d", &emp.salary);

       emps[i] = createEmployee(emp.first, emp.last, emp.title, emp.salary);
   }

    printf("Do you want to print out your information? (Y/N):");
        scanf("%c", &decision);

    if (decision == 'y' || decision == 'Y')
    {


            printEmployee(emps[1]);

    }

}
```

I don't know what the problem is. I 'm always getting the following error message after typing in **first, last, title and salary** for the **first** time. The error is written in german. It means: 
*Unhandled exception at 0x102de42e (msvcr100d.dll) in 7.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when writing to 0xCCCCCCCC position.*

[image]

I could fix the first problem with the hints given below. Now when i want to print out the employee data using the function:`printEmployee(emps[1]);`, I get the same kind of error with access violation.

Comment: You should try stepping through it with a debugger to find out *where* the problem is. The two answers posted so far point out one possible place.

Comment: Just a general hint: if you build your code with -Wall, usually you can catch lot of simple mistakes regarding scanf(), printf() and struct.field instead of struct->field

Comment: Sorry i don't know what you mean. What is Wall?

Comment: `-Wall` is a gcc compile option that turns on lots of warnings. Use it and pay heed. Other compilers probably have a similar option.

Answer (score 3):

For scanf for a number you need to specify the pointer to the number not the number itself. I.e.

```
scanf("%d", &emp.salary);
```

There may be other problems, but that's the first one I saw.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Only the printEmployee(emps[i]) doesn't work but i think i can fix that on my own.

Comment: It should be compulsory to post a comment when down-voting. Why would anyone down-vote this answer? Did I get anything wrong?

Comment: @AlastairG I don't see a down-vote for you. (Not sure who else down-voted me though.)

Comment: Sorry, I must take away the accept answer since i still get an memory error when i want to print out the employee data.

Comment: @Ordo See my second answer for your `printf()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520058/memory-error-access-violation/4520352#4520352

Comment: @Ordo, I did say there might be other problems. @Chrisayock, it showed up in my responses list. Maybe there's a bug in the site because I quite often get down votes reported but when I look at my answer it has a positive score.

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf()` arguments look off:

```
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %d",
                p->first,
                p->last,
                p->salary,  // did you mean title here rather than salary?
                p->salary
        );
```

Also, you'll want to include new line character at the end of your format string:

```
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %d\n",  // note the \n
        ...
```

---

Your `createEmployee()` definition is also questionable:

```
    p->salary, salary;  // did you mean p->salary = salary?
```

Comment: Thank you. This is definetly wrong but the error is still the same.

Comment: @Ordo Ok, found another issue involving your `createEmployee()`. My answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you're calling `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%s", emp.salary);
```

This is how you're supposed to call `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%s", &emp.salary);  // note the address to the location you want
```

**EDIT:** As AlstairG points out, your strings (the `char*` members) are pointers and thus have the address already.

Comment: `emp.first` is a string. For strings you pass the buffer pointer itself, not a pointer to that. In other words he got that right and your answer is wrong. -1 but I'll remove it if you correct your answer (and I see that in time).

Answer (score 0):

don't know, if it's the only issue, but one trouble is :

***scanf("%d", emp.salary);***

Which is wrong (forgot address on salary with &)

better try : **scanf("%d", &emp.salary);**

++